# Designing multiservice architecture with public services and Consul.io

Tags: rest, web, architecture, microservices, consul

I have a design question about a microservice setup with service discovery using Consul.io (might be applicable to other service discovery tools).

(All services and web-nodes will be built using the .NET framework)

We're building a solution with 2 or more front-end nodes and a series of services at the backend. One of these services will be providing a product search to the front-end websites. We're thinking of using Consul.io for providing redundency for these services. The front-end will be using AngularJS to show the products using a REST endpoint to query. My question is what would be the better setup for this:

- each web node hosts its own product service which relays to an internal product service using a Consul.io lookup (health check etc)
- the frontend client connect directly to the product service.

In the second case I'm wondering how the client would connect to the backend service and how discovery works. Also, I'm wondering which of those two would be the better design choice. It seems to me that using the first option would bring overhead by doing two HTTP calls.

I'm looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This does not matter, as this kind of decision is usually should be made based on your own architecture preferences and limitations. It depends on what do you think of is Better for you, cuz it is strictly architectural. It is more about defining how do you like you data streams to flow.

What I can offer to think of here, is why do you want to use Consul? Because Consul would not give you a redundancy. It's a dynamic service discovery solution. You use it when you have a lot of dynamically appearing/disappearing services and you want to discover them and use and track their health.

If you just want redundancy in a simple static cluster, maybe simple reverse proxy servers will be a good hit for you, like haproxy, nginx, and etc.